How to compile only _start function in C?
I am testing the UART implementation on my core and have written a _start function for verification:
#define UART_BASE 0x10000000L
#define UART_TX 0
void _start() {
    *(volatile char *)(UART_BASE + UART_TX) = 'A';
    *(volatile char *)(UART_BASE + UART_TX) = '\n';
    while (1);
}

Below are the compilation flags I have set and the Makefile:

CFLAGS = -nostartfiles -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -march=rv32e_zicsr -mabi=ilp32e -fno-pic -mcmodel=medany -mstrict-align -static
LDFLAGS = -e _start -T linker.ld
COPYFLAGS = --only-section=.text

uart_test.bin:uart_test.elf
    riscv64-linux-gnu-objcopy -O binary $^ $@ $(COPYFLAGS)
    riscv64-linux-gnu-objdump -d $^ > uart_test.txt

uart_test.elf:uart_test.c
    riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)


linker.ld:

ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0X20000000;
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}


When I checked the uart_test.txt file, I found that the entry point is 0x20000024 instead of the expected 0x20000000:

Disassembly of section .text:

20000024 <_start>:
20000024:   ffc10113            addi    sp,sp,-4
20000028:   00812023            sw  s0,0(sp)
2000002c:   00410413            addi    s0,sp,4
20000030:   100007b7            lui a5,0x10000
20000034:   04100713            li  a4,65
20000038:   00e78023            sb  a4,0(a5) # 10000000 <_start-0x10000024>
2000003c:   100007b7            lui a5,0x10000
20000040:   00a00713            li  a4,10
20000044:   00e78023            sb  a4,0(a5) # 10000000 <_start-0x10000024>
20000048:   0000006f            j   20000048 <_start+0x24>


When I am using readelf tool to display the section headers, I find before 0x20000024 there is a section classified as NOTE：
$ riscv64-linux-gnu-readelf -S char-test.elf 
There are 8 section headers, starting at offset 0x1170:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .note.gnu.bu[...] NOTE            20000000 001000 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        20000024 001024 00001c 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 3] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 001040 00002b 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 4] .riscv.attributes RISCV_ATTRIBUTE 00000000 00106b 00001a 00      0   0  1
  [ 5] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 001088 000080 10      6   7  4
  [ 6] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 001108 000017 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00111f 00004f 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), p (processor specific)


I think eliminating that NOTE section will be fine.

Did you check the map file what is located at 0x20000000? Maybe some interrupt vector table? BTW: What benefit do you expect by removing your whole environment from your project? Setting up your UART won't work better if you remove all the startup code etc.

If the address matters you need to create a custom section for this function to be placed in. Relying on a certain link order (not compilation order) is just way too brittle. Maybe there is a a CRT linked together with your program and that one is grabbing the first 0x24 bytes etc.

@Gerhardh I checked the section headers and found one section classified as NOTE is located at 0x20000000. Dose map file refer to that? The decision to remove the environment was to make the binary file minimum for the 32k SRAM

A map file is created by the linker during build process. It should contain similar information as you retrieved from the executable. Did you take a look, what is located in that NOTE section? Is 0x20000000 the address where program execution starts after a reset?

Maybe you should discard the other section such as gnu note (append below to ur existing script):
/DISCARD/ :
{
   *(.note.*)
}


I add -Wl,--build-id=none for CFLAGS  and solve it.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
